# Oracle SQL to traverse column for following values within a group

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written a procedure to get data ordered like below which means that user with ID 1 traverses from a->b->c->d->e->g->b->f .I want to select that ID where user visits page b after visiting page d,this case suffices for ID 1. Since my pages are very long i was looking for a solution where "string too long" error doesn't come
In a data like :

```
ID    Value
1     a
1     b
1     c
1     d
1     e
1     g
1     b
1     f
2     b
2     c
2     d
2     g
```

Output:

ID 
1

Can anyone please help me with a sql query for the same.

Comment: Tables represent unordered sets of rows. Thus, how is "follows" defined? Is it simply where one ID is greater than another? Where one value is greater than another?

Comment: @Thomas : - Its an ordered set but not numerically because in my real code it will be alphanumeric instead or numeric. What I want in this example is to return that ID where 2 follows 5 (ID 1).It can be seen that in ID-2 , value 2 precedes 5 hence result doesn't contain ID 2.

Comment: @user2342436 - Tables are *unordered* sets of rows. By definition. They are *only* ordered when you query against them with an `Order By` clause. Thus, there is no guarantee that two identical Select statements against the same data both without an Order By will return the data in the same order. Only an Order By guarantees that.

Comment: @user2342436 - Thus, given that, is "follows" defined as `UserId A = UserId B + 1`?

Comment: @user2342436 - Is "follows" defined as the sequence of rows ordered by Id then Value (which isn't what we see here)?

Comment: @Thomas : That true!! Actually in my code am running a procedure to get data ordered in this way. After getting that data i want to do some mining based on the logic i mentioned above. Please let me know if some other information is required from my side

Comment: @Thomas I think i was unclear in posting my question. I will edit the data with variables again and post it.

Comment: @user2342436 - Can you show us the expected outputted rows?

Comment: @Thomas : Output should be ID 1. Please see if my question is clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me assume that your data has a `createdat` date for ordering purposes (an incremental id would also work).  The following query expresses what you want:

```
select distinct id
from t
where value = 'b' and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id and t2.value = 'd' and t2.createdat < t.createdat
             )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was wondering if we can do this in another way where ID or date column won't be required. This is because my table is too huge and addition of an ID column will take time again

Comment: @user2342436 . . . In a single word "no".  Tables are unordered.  If you only have inserts into the table *and* you have an Oracle instance that has only one thread and no parallelism in the disk system, you *could* try `rownum`.  But that is not guaranteed to work.  *And* it will not work under most circumstances.  Having an auto incremented primary key is a good idea in every table, and this is an example of where it is useful.